# calculation with mysql im having a trouble working it out

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys ive been trying to do this one all night and i dont know if im either approching it wrong or its just not possible. i have tried multiple ways of doing it but havent succeded.

basically i have 2 tables one called user level and one called stafflist

now in the user level table i have 2 companies with 3 userlevels for each so

```
company userlevel
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
```

now in the stafflist table there are lets say 40 staff members and each have a field filled in which is the company with either 1 or 2 
they also each have a user level assigned. so 1 , 2 or 3

what i want is for the query to count how many staff are assigned each level for that company so the end result is a table like

```
company userlevel number of staff
1   1         15
1   2         3
1   3         2
2   1         18
2   2         2
2   3         0
```

could someone explain how i would go about this. ill figure out the exact code but i just need a shove in the right direction
an exaple would be really appreciated

my current code is

```
$sql = "select options.company, options.user_level, options.branch, userlevel.Description,  branch.branch as branch from options 
      left join branch on options.branch=branch.branchid 
      left join userlevel on options.user_level=userlevel.level 
      where options.user_level != '0' And options.user_level != '2' And options.user_level != '4' AND options.company='".$_SESSION['company']."'
      " ;
```

Comment: In your result example, you are retrieving values for `userlevel` 2, but in your query you are filtering that value, is that ok?

Comment: Also, posting the table structures will make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The basics of the query would be -

```
SELECT company, userlevel, COUNT(*)
FROM stafflist
GROUP BY company, userlevel
```

Comment: thank you for you help in the end i was doing it wrong the code was SELECT options.optionsid, userlevel.Description, branch.branch, COUNT(*) AS Staff, stafflist.user_level
FROM stafflist
Left Join userlevel on stafflist.user_level=userlevel.level
Left Join branch On stafflist.branch=branch.branchid
Left Join options On userlevel.level=options.user_level Where options.branch=stafflist.branch
GROUP BY branch, user_level